# Linear equation: $(A^\top A+B^\top B + D)x=c$ where $A,B$ are structured sparse and $D$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

**Updated:** the goal is to solve $(A^\top A+B^\top B + D)x=c$. Maybe it is not necessary to compute  $(A^\top A+B^\top B + D)^{-1}$.

Denote $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)^\top\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
e &  &  & \\ 
 & e &  & \\ 
 &  & \ddots & \\ 
 &  &  & e
\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{diag}(e) & \mathrm{diag}(e) & \cdots & \mathrm{diag}(e)\end{bmatrix}$$
where $e$ appears $n$ times in $A$ and $n$ times in $B$ (i.e. $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n^2}$).

For example, if $n=3$ we have:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $D$ be a $n^2\times n^2$ diagonal matrix with positive elements.

I'm looking for an efficient way to solve the linear equation
$$(A^\top A+B^\top B + D)x=c$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is the variable.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The matrix $A^TA+B^TB+D$ is *block* diagonal, the blocks having a form $\tilde{D}+ee^T$, where $\tilde{D}$ is diagonal (a block from $D$ plus an identity). To invert them, use the Woodbury formula.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: thanks for your comment, but I don't think that matrix is block diagonal. Indeed, we have:

Comment: $A^\top A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\          
\end{bmatrix}$
while $B^\top B = \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: True, I was looking on that from "other" side :) You can still use the Woodbury formula though. Let me think of it a bit.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: I refreshed the page to see your updated anwser but it disappeared. Did you find some mistakes?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot some terms.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: what I want to do is not really to invert the matrix, but instead to solve a linear system. Maybe it is not necessary to invert the matrix. I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C=A^TA+B^TB+D$. You can write it as
$$
C=D+EE^T, \quad E=[A^T,B^T].
$$
The inverse can be then using the Woodbury formula written as
$$
\begin{split}
C^{-1}&=D^{-1}-D^{-1}E(I+E^TD^{1}E)^{-1}E^TD^{-1}\\
&=D^{-1}-D^{-1}[A^T,B^T]\left\{I+\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}D^{-1}[A^T,B^T]\right\}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}D^{-1}
\end{split}\tag{$*$}
$$
Assume that $D=\mathrm{diag}(D_1,\ldots,D_n)$, where each diagonal block $D_i$ is $n\times n$.
Since $A=\mathrm{diag}(e^T)$ and $B=\mathrm{diag}(I_n)$, the "small" matrix inside the curly brackets can be written as
$$
I+\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}D^{-1}[A^T,B^T]=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1+e^TD_1^{-1}e &        &           & e^TD_1^{-1} \\
          & \ddots &           & \vdots \\
          &        & 1+e^TD_n^{-1}e & e^TD_n^{-1} \\ \hline
D_1^{-1}e      &        &    D_n^{-1}e   & I+D_1^{-1}+\cdots+D_n^{-1} 
\end{array}\right].
$$
It can hence be written in the form
$$\tag{✿}
I+\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}D^{-1}[A^T,B^T]=\begin{bmatrix}\Phi&\Theta^T\\\Theta&\Sigma\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the matrices $\Phi=\mathrm{diag}(1+e^TD_i^{-1}e)_{i=1}^n$ and $\Sigma=I+D_1^{-1}+\cdots+D_n^{-1}$ are $n\times n$ diagonal matrices. The $n\times n$ matrix $\Theta$ contains in the $i$th column the entries of the diagonal of $D_i^{-1}$.
Now you can use some [block inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) formulas, e.g., both $\Phi$ and the Schur complement $\Sigma-\Theta\Phi^{-1}\Theta^T$ are invertible (the Schur complement is normally a dense matrix).
You can plug the computed inverse back to ($*$) and compute the inverse of $C^{-1}$.

Note that you actually don't need the inverse explicitly. Assuming that the matrix (✿) has a Cholesky factorisation $LL^T$, all you need is to solve the system
$$
LX=\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}
$$
with multiple right-hand sides.
Then
$$
C^{-1}=
D^{-1}-D^{-1}[A^T,B^T](LL^T)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}D^{-1}
=D^{-1}-D^{-1}X^TXD^{-1}.
$$

To solve a system with $C$, you don't need to compute $X$ but still you need to factorise the matrix (✿). You can use ($*$) to solve a system $Cx=b$ as follows:

- Compute $y=D^{-1}b$,
- Compute $z=E^Ty$,
- Solve the system with (✿) by $Lu=z$ and $L^Tv=u$,
- Compute $s=D^{-1}Ev$,
- Set $x=y-s$.

Multiplying with $E$ and $E^T$ is easy as it involves only some summations and copies.

**NOTE:** I'm afraid that there might be no nicely looking solution except in cases where $D$ is a multiple of identity (or at least the matrices $D_i$ are multiples of identity). Otherwise, $\Theta$ is a general $n\times n$ matrix (with positive entries) so the inverse of the Schur complement $\Sigma-\Theta\Phi^{-1}\Theta^T$ cannot be written in some simple form. However, in the mentioned special cases the matrix $\Theta\Phi^{-1}\Theta^T$ would have rank one so one could use the Sherman-Morrison formula to invert the Schur complement.

**NOTE 2:** The matrix (✿) has a special form so this can be somewhat exploited in the Cholesky factorisation. The matrix can be factorised as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\Phi&\Theta^T\\\Theta&\Sigma\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\\Theta\Phi^{-1}&I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Phi&0\\0&\Pi\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}I&\Phi^{-1}\Theta^T\\0&I\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\Pi=\Sigma-\Theta\Phi^{-1}\Theta^T$ is the already mentioned Schur complement.
So if $\tilde{L}\tilde{L}^T=\Pi$ is the Cholesky factorisation of $\Pi$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\Phi&\Theta^T\\\Theta&\Sigma\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\Phi^{1/2}&0\\\Theta\Phi^{-1/2}&\tilde{L}\end{bmatrix}}_{L}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\Phi^{1/2}&\Phi^{-1/2}\Theta^T\\0&\tilde{L}^T\end{bmatrix}}_{L^T}
$$
is the Cholesky factorisation of (✿). Of course, some rearrangements can be made to avoid computing the square roots.

Comment: Thanks Algebraic Pavel for your effort. I'm checking carefully your post. 
There's a small mistake in the application of the Woodbury formula, it should be $E^TD^{-1}E$ instead of $E^TDE$, but I hope this does not affect too much the other arguments. I'm still checking...

Comment: @Khue Thanks, it's fixed.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to check your answer. Everything seems to be fine except a typo in the Cholesky factorization of (✿): you forgot the transpose sign in the last matrix (it should read $\Phi^{-1}\Theta^T$ instead of $\Phi^{-1}\Theta$).

I will try to implement to see if this solution gives reasonable performance (as I see the most expensive steps are solving $Lu=z,L^Tv=u$ and the Cholesky factorization of $\Pi$).

Thanks again for your help.